# Android - Como detectar qual é o fragmento atual?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Ola, tenho um aplicativo que utiliza o sistema de fragmentos e um FloatActionButton, em um dos fragmentos eu tenho um banner de anúncio bem embaixo do FloatActionButton, eu fiz da forma abaixo, porém não funciona com os fragmentos na pilha, então, existe algum tipo de listener para identificar qual é o atual fragmento na activity?

```
        //Is Landscape or Portrait
        if(isLandscape){

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frameContainer, gallery);
            ft.commit();

        }else{

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.containerFrag, main);
            ft.commit();
            if(findViewById(R.id.fabOpenDownloaderPage).getVisibility() != View.GONE){
                findViewById(R.id.fabOpenDownloaderPage).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

        PrimaryDrawerItem itemHome = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.navD_item_home).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_home).withIdentifier(ID_HOME_ITEM).withSelectable(false);
        PrimaryDrawerItem itemGallery = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.navD_item_gallery).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_movies).withIdentifier(ID_GALLERY_ITEM).withSelectable(false);
        PrimaryDrawerItem itemSettings = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.navD_item_settings).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_settings).withIdentifier(ID_SETTINGS_ITEM).withSelectable(false);
        SecondaryDrawerItem itemAbout = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.navD_item_about).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_outline).withIdentifier(ID_ABOUT_ITEM).withSelectable(false);

        Drawer navDrawer = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(tbMain)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
                .withSelectedItem(-1)
                .addDrawerItems(itemHome, itemGallery, itemSettings, new DividerDrawerItem(), itemAbout)
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

                        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                        switch((int)drawerItem.getIdentifier()){

                            case (int)ID_HOME_ITEM:
                                if(!isLandscape){
                                    ft.replace(R.id.containerFrag, main);
                                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                                    ft.commit();
                                    if(findViewById(R.id.fabOpenDownloaderPage).getVisibility() != View.GONE){
                                        findViewById(R.id.fabOpenDownloaderPage).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                                break;

                            case (int)ID_GALLERY_ITEM:
                                if(isLandscape){
                                    ft.replace(R.id.frameContainer, gallery);
                                    ft.commit();
                                }else{
                                    ft.replace(R.id.containerFrag, gallery);
                                    ft.addToBackStack(main.TAG);
                                    ft.commit();
                                    if(findViewById(R.id.fabOpenDownloaderPage).getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                                        findViewById(R.id.fabOpenDownloaderPage).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    }
                                }
                                break;

                            case (int)ID_SETTINGS_ITEM:

                                if(isLandscape){
                                    ft.replace(R.id.frameContainer, settings);
                                    ft.addToBackStack(gallery.TAG);
                                    ft.commit();
                                }else{
                                    ft.replace(R.id.containerFrag, settings);
                                    ft.addToBackStack(main.TAG);
                                    ft.commit();
                                    if(findViewById(R.id.fabOpenDownloaderPage).getVisibility() != View.GONE){
                                        findViewById(R.id.fabOpenDownloaderPage).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                                break;

                            case (int)ID_ABOUT_ITEM:
                                if(isLandscape){
                                    ft.replace(R.id.frameContainer, about);
                                    ft.commit();
                                }else{
                                    ft.replace(R.id.containerFrag, about);
                                    ft.addToBackStack(main.TAG);
                                    ft.commit();
                                    if(findViewById(R.id.fabOpenDownloaderPage).getVisibility() != View.GONE){
                                        findViewById(R.id.fabOpenDownloaderPage).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                                break;

                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

Coloque uma tag, ao abrir o fragment:

```
frag.replace(android.R.id.content, myFragment, "MY_FRAGMENT");
```

Então, você poderá saber qual está ativo:

```
MeuFragment meuFragment = (MeuFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MeuFragment");
if (meFragment != null && meuFragment.isVisible()) {
   // seu código :)
}
```

Comment: Eu adicionei no onCreate da activity mas não funcionou